# EPG on Android vlc project

Tags: java, android, vlc, vlc-android

How to get EPG using android-vlc

I am currently implementing 'com.yyl.vlc:vlc-android-sdk:3.0.13' package for using android-vlc player into my project. 
In this project i am trying to implement IPTV. I don't know how to get EPG from the android vlc. When i use vlc on desktop i can detect the EPG via Tools > Program Guide option. 
Which is the the function i have to use from the LIBVLC MediaPlayer class, LIBVLC MediaPlayer class or from IVLCVout class?

Comment: this might only work with `DVB-C` channels.

Comment: @MartinZeitler thx for the reply, i edited the question. I am already reading EPG via vlc desktop

Comment: Did you managed to get EPG information in android app?

Comment: @Jon No Jon, left it without any info